# npm is only updating when changes are made in index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have just started learning React and I am running the server with the command npm start but the problem is whenever I am making any changes in the index.js file it is updating it on the website but whenever I am importing some other apps and making changes in those apps it is not updating the website .
How can I update my site on updating any file in the project ?

Here is my header.js file

```js
import React from 'react';

const user = {

    name : 'Brijesh',
    lastname : 'Maurya',
    age : 20
}

const Header = () =>{

return (   
    <div>
        <div>{user.name}</div>
    </div>)
}

export default Header;
```

Here is index.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Components 
import Header from './components/header'

const App = () =>{

    return (

        <div>
            <Header/>
        </div>
    )
}  

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: can you be more specific or explanatory about  "I am importing some other apps and making changes in those apps"? importing apps into a project i did not quiet understand it?...

Comment: have you tried npm run watch ?

Comment: @pavankumar I have two files index.js and header.js and whenever I make any change in index.js it works fine and update the website dynamically but when I am making any changes in header.js then I need to restart the server for changes to take effect .

Comment: @RicardoRaz I tried but still not working .

Comment: @unknown I tried adding semicolon but still not working .

Comment: @Brijesh how did you create your react app? via create-react-app ?

Comment: @RicardoRaz Yeah I made a directory for project and used "create-react-app ." command .

Comment: @Brijesh it is weird, as npm start should execute react-scripts start which has hot module reloading.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoRaz You are right .  I just tried to make changes in index.js and it didn't updated it but it was updating a few minutes ago . can you please tell me what could I have done wrong ?

Comment: Can you try create a new react-app?

Comment: Okay I'll do and tell you the results in few minutes . Thanks

Comment: @RicardoRaz Yeah Thank you so much for help . On creating another app it is working fine but I have no idea what I did wrong in the previous one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your issue is resolved by creating another app , maybe you should think over the flow you went through while making those files . 
As you mentioned that you have just started learning react , I think you might have done something like deleting all the files and then creating new files from scratch.

Anyways , welcome to the world of React JS !

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like whatever server npm start is running - probably a node server - has Hot Module Replacement configured and for the other apps that you are running HMR is not configured.

You can learn more about how to configure HMR on Webpack's site here:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/

And about React Hot Loader here:
https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/

If npm start runs the wepack-dev-server it may be as simple as running the server with the --hot flag.

Comment: I think it is too complicated and I would rather use other available options . I just want to know why it is not updating the site when I make changes in other files except index.js